# Java HashMap and Object keys

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

## Example

```
LinkedHashMap<Long, String> myHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
myHashMap.put(new Long(1), "A Value");
```

## Questions

1. Is the key a reference or a copy?
2. If I write `String aValue = myHashMap.get(new Long(1));`, will I get `"A Value"` back? Or have I just queried for a different object (reference) and therefore I'll get an error?

Comment: What happened when you tried it? What does the javadoc of `HashMap` say?

Comment: The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)'s 5th paragraph ("If many mappings...") says something about `hashCode()`, but I can't quite get the answer I need. Could point out the portion I need to read/focus on?

Comment: @sargas Your question doesn't mention `hashCode`. The `hashCode` is used to determine the index of the array the entry is stored in. If too many entries have the same `hashCode`, it will slow down the performance.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Correct. And I just found what I was looking for in the [Map Interface documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The key is a reference to the same instance.
2. You will get `"A Value"` back, because `Long` has overridden

   - `equals()` (`return value == obj.longValue()`),
   - `hashCode()` (`return Long.hashCode(value)`).

Comment: Your answer is very insightful to me. I ended up having to read the [Map Interface's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) to find this information (rather than the HashMap or LinkedHashMap ones).

Answer (score 5):

1. The map stores a a copy of the reference to the object passed as argument. No copy of objects is made.
2. Yes, you will get "A Value" back, as documented. A Map compares its keys with equals(), not `==` (except for IdentityHashMap). You could test that pretty easily, BTW.

Comment: Doesn't the map store the "hashCode()" of the object?  And then compare the hashs with == ?  If you implement equals() you are always supposed to implement hashCode for this specific reason

Comment: Yes, it does. But equal hashCodes doesn't mean that objects are equal. In the end, keys are compared with equals(). My point is that it doesn't tests if keys are `==`, but if keys are equal.